# How can chaincode send error messages back to the application where call came from?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have been developing an application involving a frontend that makes call to blockchain chaincode.

Chaincode returns an OK message for all the transactions that are sent. Even failed transactions have OK as the response. Although errors can be seen in the blockchain logs.

Is there a way to make the chaincode send an error message all the way back to the frontend in case an error happens so that frontend knows whether a transaction was successful or not?

Answer (score 2):

Chaincode should conform to the following APIs:

```
// Chaincode interface must be implemented by all chaincodes. The fabric runs
// the transactions by calling these functions as specified.
type Chaincode interface {
    // Init is called during Instantiate transaction after the chaincode container
    // has been established for the first time, allowing the chaincode to
    // initialize its internal data
    Init(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response

    // Invoke is called to update or query the ledger in a proposal transaction.
    // Updated state variables are not committed to the ledger until the
    // transaction is committed.
    Invoke(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response
}
```

Where `pb.Response` is:

```
// A response with a representation similar to an HTTP response that can
// be used within another message.
type Response struct {
    // A status code that should follow the HTTP status codes.
    Status int32 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=status" json:"status,omitempty"`
    // A message associated with the response code.
    Message string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=message" json:"message,omitempty"`
    // A payload that can be used to include metadata with this response.
    Payload []byte `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=payload,proto3" json:"payload,omitempty"`
}
```

Chaincode shim provides facade functions to return error and success statuses defined in [response.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/response.go). Therefore while implementting a flow on your chaincode you can use different response types to signal and forward the error back to the client side, for [example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02.go#L75):

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("ex02 Invoke")
    function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    if function == "invoke" {
        // Make payment of X units from A to B
        return t.invoke(stub, args)
    } else if function == "delete" {
        // Deletes an entity from its state
        return t.delete(stub, args)
    } else if function == "query" {
        // the old "Query" is now implemtned in invoke
        return t.query(stub, args)
    }

    return shim.Error("Invalid invoke function name. Expecting \"invoke\" \"delete\" \"query\"")
}
```

Will respond with error if you will try to invoke chaincode with wrong parameters set. Later you can inspect response to see whenever there is an error or not happened also you can extend your response with message to give more details about what happened.